# Why is the user@domain and cn=user,dc=domain not equivalent?

Tags: ldap, aws-directory-service

I've setup a Simple AD on AWS that I can finally authenticate against with LDAP. I don't understand why I was unable to use `dc=` which is widely suggested everywhere but am able to use `@domain`.

```
ldap_bind($ldapconn, "cn=Administrator,dc=ldap,dc=patontheback,dc=org", "<password>");
ldap_bind($ldapconn, "Administrator@ldap.patontheback.org", "<password>");
```

Are these not supposed to be equivalent? Will @domain always work or it specific to Simple AD?

[image]

Comment: Please check the correct location of the Administrator user in LDAP. Is it really in the LDAP section or is it in a sub? (users, system,...whatever). You have to match the entire path of the object (the admin user in your case).

Comment: @Zina It's in Users (added screenshot). How would I go about selecting it? I've tried `dc=`, `ou=`, `Users\Administrator` but I feel that I'm just fumbling in the dark.

Comment: it is `cn=Administrator,ou=Users,dc=ldap,dc=pathontheback,dc=org`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP gave additional information of the location of the Administrator user so he has to use `cn=Administrator,ou=Users,dc=ldap,dc=pathontheback,dc=org`

EDIT:
Made a typo, it has to be:
`cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=ldap,dc=pathontheback,dc=org`

Users is a container, not OU.

Comment: I've tried it but I'm not able to connect with:  **cn=Administrator,ou=Users,dc=ldap,dc=patontheback,dc=org** and I've checked that I can continue to connect with the UPN version.

Comment: Strange. Would you use a LDAP browser where you can copy the dname? eg. ldp.exe (I think it is in the RSAT) or http://www.ldapadmin.org/ and see if maybe I made a typo?

Comment: Ah ha! Instead of `ou=Users` it wanted `cn=Users`. Thanks!

Comment: @KitSunde You'll note in `dsa.msc` container objects (cn=) are represented by a 'blank' folder icon -- visible in your question's screenshot. organizationalUnit (ou=) is a folder with what looks like a phone book on them.

Answer (score 5):

A [bit of reading](https://www.ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns) on LDAP and DNs might be in order here.

> A distinguished name (usually just shortened to DN) both uniquely identifies an entry and describes its position in the DIT. A DN is much like an absolute path on a filesystem, except whereas filesystem paths usually start with the root of the filesystem and descend the tree from left to right, LDAP DNs ascend the tree from left to right.

So if you want to specify the DN of the administrator account in your domain, you need to specify the full (and correct) path to it.  As your screenshot shows (and the fact that it's standard in AD), the administrator account is in the Users container.

Note that I used the word **container** and not OU. Not every container in AD is an OU and most of the default ones that exist actually aren't.  You can tell at a glance by comparing the icon for `Users` with the icon for `Domain Controllers`. If that's too subtle, you can also check the actual `objectClass` attribute for each one.  OU's will contain `organizationalUnit` and normal containers will have `container`.  In a DN value, OU's have "OU=" as their RDN key, and containers have "CN=" as their RDN key.

In any case, you don't really have to figure this all out manually when you're looking for something's DN day-to-day.  Just open (or query) the properties of the object you're looking for and check the `distinguishedName` attribute.  That will give you the full and correct path without trying to manually string together a bunch of RDNs and contexts yourself.

**TL;DR**
The DN for the administrator account in your example domain is `CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ldap,DC=patontheback,DC=org`

That said, it's better practice to keep doing what you're doing and use the UPN *(user@domain.example.com)* for bind accounts against AD because they're less likely to change than a DN value.

Answer (score 0):

[@Ryan Bolger answer](https://serverfault.com/a/775699/71120) has a very good explanation. I wanted to include a more complete example for those who like to see what happens with various commands.

For example I use the following for the binddn `distinguishedName: CN=auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,DC=localdomain,DC=lan`

```
-D 'CN=auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,DC=localdomain,DC=lan'
```

or the UPN `userPrincipalName: gitlab@nmm.lan`

```
-D 'auser@localdomain.lan'
```

The following lines will produce the same output below

```
ldapsearch -x -h '192.168.0.10' -D 'CN=Auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,DC=localdomain,DC=lan' -w password -b"cn=auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,dc=localdomain,dc=lan" -s sub "objectclass=*"
```

or

```
ldapsearch -x -h '192.168.0.10' -D 'auser@localdomain.lan' -w password -b"cn=auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,dc=localdomain,dc=lan" -s sub "objectclass=*"
```

The same output will be generated

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,dc=localdomain,dc=lan> with scope subtree
# filter: objectclass=*
# requesting: ALL
#

# auser, IT Dev, localdomain Users, localdomain.lan
dn: CN=GitLab,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,DC=localdomain,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: auser
givenName: auser
distinguishedName: CN=auser,OU=IT Dev,OU=localdomain Users,DC=localdomain,DC=lan
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20190221073536.0Z
whenChanged: 20190221080923.0Z
displayName: auser
uSNCreated: 108114404
memberOf: CN=groupofusers,OU=localdomain Groups,DC=localdomain,DC=lan
uSNChanged: 108116177
name: auser
userAccountControl: 66048
codePage: 0
countryCode: 0
primaryGroupID: 513
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
sAMAccountName: auser
sAMAccountType: 805306368
userPrincipalName: auser@localdomain.lan
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=localdomain,DC=lan
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
lastLogonTimestamp: 131952101637691018

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```